# how can I filter an objects in json file with the aid of two common value? I mean I want to filter the json objects in terms of common x and y

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

there is a json file and I want to separate the objects in terms of common x and y. I mean I want to put together the objects with the same `x` and `y`.
I have a json file like the following :

```
let data = [{
"x" = "0",
"y" = "0",
"k" = "0"
},
{
"x" = "0",
"y" = "0",
"k" = "1"
},
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "0"
},
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "5"
},
{
"x" = "2",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "10"
},
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "12"
}
]
```

and I want to get the result like the following :

```
result = [
[{
"x" = "0",
"y" = "0",
"k" = "0"
},
{
"x" = "0",
"y" = "0",
"k" = "1"
}],
[
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "0"
},
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "5"
},
{
"x" = "1",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "12"
}
],
[{
"x" = "2",
"y" = "2",
"k" = "10"
}]
]
```

I want to just separate the objects with the common `x` and `y`,
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```js
// if you know that a certain character like "-" doesn't exist in x / y
const group = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
  const key = `${item.x}-${item.y}`;
  group[key] = [];
  group[key].push(item);
});

const result = Object.values(group);

// if there is no separator guarantee 
const group = {};
data.forEach((item) => {
  group[item.x] = group[item.x] || {};
  group[item.x][item.y] = group[item.x][item.y] || [];
  group[item.x][item.y].push(item);
});

const result = Object.values(group).map(item => Object.values(item)).flat();
```

Comment: Hi, i want to push the items which has same x and y, I mean x in obj1 is equal to x in obj2.